# Shell Script assigning sql query to variable

Tags: sql, bash, shell

I am assigning a select statement which will return a column of names to a variable "out" in shell script. I want to make a conditional that will say: if that OUT variable has any names, then do "something". How can i do this? can I simply say if OUT>=1? Can I use out as a numeric variable, or is it a string variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way where you can run the query as follows :

Assume the query is "SELECT column1 from table"

```
$count = $dbh->do("SELECT COUNT(*) from (
           SELECT column1 from table
       )");
if($count>1)
    do X;
else
    do Y;
```

Hope this helps where you use the count function to get a return value of the output and then use it as a variable for if and else condition.